# Android WebView not fully decoding String

Tags: android, encoding, utf-8, webview, xamarin.android

I have a very simple `WebView` that needs to display text as HTML.  I retrieve data from a server that is in a `byte` array.  I need to display that `byte` array as readable text.

```
var wv = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webview);

var container = AutoFac.Container;
_routinesService = container.Resolve<IRoutinesService>();
byte[] documentHtml = _routinesService.GetFragment(documentId);

string mimeType = "text/html";
string encoding = "utf-8";
var html = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(documentHtml);

wv.LoadDataWithBaseURL("", html, mimeType, encoding, "");
```

I try to convert the `byte` array to a `String`, and the variable `html` becomes `\"U3RlcCAxOiBZb3UgYXJlIGEgd2lubmVyLg==\"`

This looks like Base64 to me, and when I use an online converter (https://www.base64decode.org/), it does convert to the correct text.  But the output on the screen in the `WebView` just looks like `"U3RlcCAxOiBZb3UgYXJlIGEgd2lubmVyLg=="`

Any ideas what I might be missing?

Just for more information, this is in Xamarin.Android so the code is C# instead of Java (but there is not much difference).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried javascript

> atob()

method that decodes a string of data which has been encoded using base-64 encoding before posting it to webview.

Comment: I have not.  The WebView only needs to display HTML so I do not want to have to add the ability to run javascript in it.  I have tried using Convert.ToBase64String, converting that string back into a byte array, and then decoding it as UTF8 again but get the same result.